# cpp: how to define dynamically allocated field from pointers to Class?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, allocation

How i can dynamically allocated field from pointers to Class in c++?

Here is my class Vehicle

```
class Veh{
protected:
    double weight;
    int width,height;
public:
    Vozilo(double weight=0, int width=0,int height=0)
    {
        this->weight=weight;
        this->width=width;
        this->height=height;
    }
    ~Veh(){}
};
```

In this class i want to allocate field from pointers to Veh class

```
class Parking
{
private:
    Vozilo *ptr;
    int len;
public:
    Parking(Vozilo *ptr, int len)
    {
        this-> *ptr = new *Vozilo[len];
    }
};
```

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: use a `std::vector`

Comment: @idclev463035818 can you give me an example?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Btw. you should decide whether to use `Veh` or `Vozilo`. The current mix won't work. ;-) (The C++ compiler is as peculiar about this as me.)

Comment: @Scheff ahh i forgot to change Vozilo to Veh..